# Format all elements of a list

Tags: python, list, string-formatting, python-2.x

I want to print a list of numbers, but I want to format each member of the list before it is printed.
For example,

```
theList=[1.343465432, 7.423334343, 6.967997797, 4.5522577]
```

I want the following output printed given the above list as an input:

```
[1.34, 7.42, 6.97, 4.55]
```

For any one member of the list, I know I can format it by using

```
print "%.2f" % member
```

Is there a command/function that can do this for the whole list? I can write one, but was wondering if one already exists.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want to print the numbers you can use a simple loop:

```
for member in theList:
    print "%.2f" % member
```

If you want to store the result for later you can use a list comprehension:

```
formattedList = ["%.2f" % member for member in theList]
```

You can then print this list to get the output as in your question:

```
print formattedList
```

Note also that `%` is being deprecated. If you are using Python 2.6 or newer prefer to use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I don't know how to use `format` yet. But will learn.

Answer (score 10):

For Python 3.5.1, you can use:

```
>>> theList = [1.343465432, 7.423334343, 6.967997797, 4.5522577]
>>> strFormat = len(theList) * '{:10f} '
>>> formattedList = strFormat.format(*theList)
>>> print(formattedList)
```

The result is:

```
'  1.343465   7.423334   6.967998   4.552258 '
```

Comment: I modified this using `strFormat = '[' + (len(theList)-1) * '{:10f}, ' + '{:10f}]'`

Answer (score 10):

A very short solution using "".format() and a generator expression:

```
>>> theList=[1.343465432, 7.423334343, 6.967997797, 4.5522577]

>>> print(['{:.2f}'.format(item) for item in theList])

['1.34', '7.42', '6.97', '4.55']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension, join and some string manipulation, as follows:

```
>>> theList=[1.343465432, 7.423334343, 6.967997797, 4.5522577]
>>> def format(l):
...     return "["+", ".join(["%.2f" % x for x in l])+"]"
... 
>>> format(theList)
'[1.34, 7.42, 6.97, 4.55]'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the map function

```
l2 = map(lambda n: "%.2f" % n, l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you don't need to save your values:

```
list = [0.34555, 0.2323456, 0.6234232, 0.45234234]
for member in list:
    form='{:.1%}'.format(member)
    print(form)
```

output:

```
34.6%
23.2%
62.3%
45.2%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper function:

```py
def format_list(a, fmt, sep=', ', start='[', end=']'):
    return start + sep.join([format(x, fmt) for x in a]) + end
```

usage:

```py
a=[4,8,15,16,23,42]

print(f"%d is {format_list(a, 'd')} %x is {format_list(a, 'x')} %b is {format_list(a, 'b')}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use f-strings and a list comprehension:

```
 print([f'{item: .2f}' for item in theList])
```